# Expanding mapbox popup on click

Tags: popup, mapbox

Does anyone know how I can expand a marker popup/infobox on click in mapboxgl ?

At the moment, what I have is the following. When a user hovers  over a marker, a popup appears, displaying the name of a venue.

```html
var infobox = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: false
            })

map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
   var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                layers: [‘layer’]
            });
         
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';

    if (!features.length) {
        infobox.remove();
        return;
     }

    var feature = features[0];
            infobox.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .setHTML(‘Venue name’)
                .addTo(map);
});
```

What I need to implement apart from this is:  When a user clicks on the marker,  the popup expands, showing along with the venue’s name, its description. The popup stays open until the user clicks somewhere else on the map.
Does anyone know how to do this in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
// create DOM element for the marker
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'marker';

// create the popup
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
.setText('Venue name');

new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(monument)
.setPopup(popup) // sets a popup on this marker
.addTo(map);
```

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-popup/